# Does Swing's removeAll() set all removed elements to null?

Tags: java, swing, garbage-collection, removeall

Does the `Container` `removeAll()` method set the value of all removed components to `null`? If so, how can I remove all elements from a `Container` without setting them to null? If not, how can I ensure the garbage collector removes unused elements after I've overwritten them?

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/awt/Container.java#Container.removeAll%28%29

Comment: Have you tried to read docs ? or source code ?

Comment: Jigar Joshi: Ah. The second and third part of my question have been resolved now. Thanks!

Suresh Atta: I read the docs, but they didn't have anything about that. The source code, however, was very useful. I didn't know it was online (though I probably should have.

Thank you both for your help!

Comment: No issues. We all faced that issue. That is fine. Please mark as answer if you found it helpful :)

Comment: Will do! I have to wait nine minutes, though. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the Container removeAll() method set the value of all removed components to null?

**Yes** (See [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/awt/Container.java#Container.removeAll%28%29))

> How can I remove all elements from a Container without setting them to null?

`Container` has an array of `Components` associated with it, if you want to remove it you either set it to `null` or set it to some other value

> How can I ensure the garbage collector removes unused elements after I've overwritten them?

if there is no active reference to those `Component` instances it will be eligible for GC